# Elasticsearch for setting index "no" which type to use, keyword or text?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch for setting "index": "no", with "index": false what should we use for "type", "keyword" OR "text" Will there be any difference?

Because as the field is not indexed I don't think there would be any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `index` option to `no` in Elasticsearch 2.x or to `false` in Elasticsearch > 5.x will not create an [inverted index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html) for that field which means you cannot perform searching or filtering on it. But you can do sorting and aggregations by creating a view on the data called `fielddata`using [doc_values](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9762)  which is where `type` of the field matters.   
 
 I created `my_index` with `text_or_keyword_field` and ran a search query by setting the field's`type` to `text` once and to `keyword` the next time.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "text_or_keyword_field": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch raised a `search_phase_execution_exception` giving the expected reason:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"match\" : {\n    \"text_or_keyword_field\" : {\n      \"query\" : \"brown fox\",\n      \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n      \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n      \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n      \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n      \"lenient\" : false,\n      \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n      \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n      \"boost\" : 1.0\n    }\n  }\n}",
        "index_uuid": "hz4Vq6mPRaCc9HSxB-MEYg",
        "index": "my_index"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "my_index",
        "node": "LvCoGAkyTbiVIeyF7UtXTw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"match\" : {\n    \"text_or_keyword_field\" : {\n      \"query\" : \"brown fox\",\n      \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n      \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n      \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n      \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n      \"lenient\" : false,\n      \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n      \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n      \"boost\" : 1.0\n    }\n  }\n}",
          "index_uuid": "hz4Vq6mPRaCc9HSxB-MEYg",
          "index": "my_index",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Cannot search on field [text_or_keyword_field] since it is not indexed."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, but sorry I didn't get you properly, so you meant you tried two mappings one with "type" as "keyword" and other with "type" as "text", next when you performed the search query for both of them you got the above error? Am i right? Also as I am indexing the field as "false" why do you think I would query for it, as I am indexing it as "false" I don't want to query for it. I just want to know whether there would be any difference when I would use type as "keyword" and "text" and set index to "false", thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. There would be no difference if you're not using doc_values. I have edited the answer with further explanation.